# Finding timestamp range while value is in a range

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have a database with

```
id     time                   value
1      2016-10-18 12:42:37    1
2      2016-10-18 12:43:37    2
3      2016-10-18 12:44:37    3
4      2016-10-18 12:45:37    0
5      2016-10-18 12:46:37    1
6      2016-10-18 12:47:37    3
7      2016-10-18 12:48:37    0
```

is there any way to get back the time stamp range when the value is not 0? I.E

```
start                  stop                    length
2016-10-18 12:42:37    2016-10-18 12:45:37     3 min
2016-10-18 12:46:37    2016-10-18 12:48:37     2 min
```

answer does not need to be exactly like this.  just trying to see if there is a better way to get the data then stepping through the database in php.

Comment: Are your `id` values *guaranteed* to be in the same order as your `time` values?

Comment: usually.  but no guarantee.